# Disable Marketplace from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Neon on a virtual machine without Internet connection.

I frequently get the annoying prompt "Search Marketplace for compatible editor has encountered a problem", how can I disable the lookup for editors or just entirely the Marketplace?

Comment: Annoying indeed. Does this happen to you only when you open files? It happens to me whenever I checkout new code (it thinks I might want to install the Spring nature). I don't even have to open a file to trigger it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Eclipse is noticing that you are opening a file type that it doesn't have an associated editor. When it goes to find an editor in the market place, the server is returning something that eclipse doesn't understand. There appears to be a related bug [2] and a patch is coming. For now, you have a couple of options.

**Option 1: Tell eclipse to stop looking at the marketplace**  when opening a file that does not have an associated file.

From the menu bar,

1. Select: window
2. Select: preferences

In the preferences dialog box,

1. Search for: File Associations
2. Scroll all the way down to the end. It's easy to miss. You need to scroll past "File types" and "Associated Editors." You will see "Open Unassociated Editors with:" followed by a drop down.
3. From the drop down, select anything other than "Search Marketplace" and the error will go away.

   - For the default behavior in Neon, select "Ask via pop-up."
   - For the behavior that is closest to what happened before neon, select "System Editor; if none: Text Editor."
   - You can also choose "Text Editor"

**Option 2: Associate the file type with an application.**

From the menu bar,

1. Select: window
2. Select: preferences

In the preferences dialog box,

1. Search for: File Associations
2. Add or select the file association from the first box called "File types"
3. Add or select an editor to associate with it from the second box called "Associated Editors"

[1] This answer is inspired by "5. File Editors" in the below link
https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2016/june/article1.php

[2] Note that the error message may be related to this bug as well. This bug says that the exception is being thrown because of a server side error. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494899

Comment: I think they moved the "Open Unassociated Editors with:" followed by a drop down to the top, at least in my version, should I edit the post?